# raw bitmap to png in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qimage, qbytearray

I have bytearray where every three bytes describes 1 pixel (RGB). The task is to convert it to jpeg or png. I receive the image palette from socket, construct its relevant RGB24 from the RGB table I have.

The problem I have is I cannot convert this bitmap to png now. for example:

```
image.loadFromData((const char*)bytes);
qDebug() << image.save("/home/saman/image.png");
```

if this is not the way, another option is adding png header to the bitmap array. However, I have no idea how to do that.

Anyone has any ideas please?

Comment: if you mention the image extension after the name, it will automatically recognize the format of it.

Comment: Err... no, not always. Read it again: "will attempt to guess".

Comment: ok, I will try it with format this time. by the way what you mean by that png imageformat plugin? QT already has libpng installed, so i do not need to install it on my linux machine

Comment: no, it is not right. as the image is bitmap with no headers libpng built inside QT would trigger error. it is not dependent to mentioning the format type.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue, so please kindly refer to [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Comment: Is this still unresolved two years later??

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in these two lines:

- Not specified save format for starter as per [official documentation:](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qimage.html#save-2).

  QImage image;
  QByteArray ba;
  QBuffer buffer(&ba);
  buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes image into ba in PNG format
- Not specified format for the loading.
- You are doing *C type cast* in a C++ code.
- You are doing the cast needlessly as there is a QByteArray overload.
- You are casting to char*, whereas the expectation for that particular overload is *unsigned* char*.
- You do not check the return value of the load operation.

  QImage image;
  QByteArray ba;
  QBuffer buffer(&ba);
  buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  image.save(&buffer, "PNG"); // writes image into ba in PNG format

So, I would write something like this in your case:

```
if (!image.loadFromData((const char*)bytes, QImage::Format_RGB888))
    qDebug() << "Could not load the image";

if (!image.save("/home/saman/image.png"), "PNG"))
    qDebug() << "Could not save the image";
```

Naturally, you would also need to make sure the width and height are correct for the image because otherwise, the raw data is just sequential, and the class instance cannot really magically figure out.

Comment: The upper code is of no use in my case. only the last two lines. It returns false. I already tried the last two lines.

Comment: What else have you tried you forgot to communicate? Anyway, you will vote for closing it until you can provide a reproducable example.

Comment: i mean your code. the upper part is writing image into ba in PNG format. we don't need that. what we need is loadFromData() and save(). saving the image with format mentioned also returns false. By the way, what makes you so sure the PNG header is automatically added to the pixmap?

Comment: @user1596226: you have not provided any examples to reproduce the issue. Moreover, you have not even followed the suggetions like checking the return value of load, setting the proper format when loading, etc... you have not tried PNG before as per your previous comment either. So much we can do for you...

Comment: something is strange, Load returns false! though I am sure bytes has contents. loadFromData(bytes.constData()) = false, why? bytes is full and right now renders all its contents to the scree.

Comment: if (!image.loadFromData((const unsigned char*)bytes.constData(), QImage::Format_RGB888))
        qDebug() << "Could not load the image";  returns FALSE

Comment: @user1596226: have you figured out the nitty-gritty details?

Answer (score 1):

it seems I shoudav used the constructor to mention bytesPerLine used.

```
  QImage *image =new QImage((const uchar*)bytes.constData(),600, 800,1800,QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

with bytes per line mentioned now everything works fine.